# How to obtain the Lagrange remainder for $\sin(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

> How do you obtain the Lagrange remainder for $\sin(x)$ or any other functions?

So the formula for the Lagrange remainder is: $$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$ for some $c\in (0,x)$ which I can believe and have seen the proof of. But then my books spits out that somehow the remainder for $\sin(x)$ is $$R_{2n+1}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cos(c)}{(2n+3)!}x^{2n+3}$$ how can you prove this formula by following the Lagrange remainder formula? I've tried it but I can't see how you get cosine everytime even for odd $n$ that you should get $\sin(c)$ in any case at all

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587554/what-is-the-lagrange-remainder-for-sin-x this may help.

Comment: I did read it before posting this but it showed $2n+2$ instead of $2n+3$ as my book says. Also I don't think it even clarifies my doubt because I'm asking how to arrive to it, not which one to use

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula for the Lagrange remainder that you give
$$
R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\tag1
$$
and substituting $n\mapsto2n+1$, we would get
$$
R_{2n+1}(x)=\frac{f^{(2n+2)}(c)}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2}\tag2
$$
However, since $\frac{f^{(2n+2)}(0)}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2}$ vanishes for $f(x)=\sin(x)$, we have $R_{2n+1}(x)=R_{2n+2}(x)$ for $\sin(x)$. Using the formula in $(1)$ and substituting $n\mapsto2n+2$, we get
$$
R_{2n+2}(x)=\frac{f^{(2n+3)}(c)}{(2n+3)!}x^{2n+3}\tag3
$$
Note that the $c$ in $R_{2n+1}(x)$, which is simply given as some real number between $0$ and $x$, is not necessarily the same as the $c$ in $R_{2n+2}(x)$. However,
$$
R_{2n+1}(x)=R_{2n+2}(x)=\sin(x)-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\tag4
$$

Comment: can you please expand on how it vanishes so that you get that $R_{2n+1}=R_{2n+2}$? And as a second smaller question, what's the motivation to do the substitution $n\mapsto 2n+1$? The rest was crystal-clear, thanks!

Comment: @Ivy Note that an even ($2n+2$) derivative of $f=\sin$ is $(-1)^{n+1}\sin$ and $(-1)^{n+1}\sin$ is $0$ at $0$.

Comment: @Ivy: as Gary says, $f^{(2n+2)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\sin(x)$ which vanishes for $x=0$. As for the second question, to get $R_{2n+1}(x)$ from the formula for $R_n(x)$, we would substitute $n\mapsto2n+1$.

Comment: Okay for the first question. But I'm looking for the motivation behind doing the sustitution $n\mapsto 2n+1$, not how or how you do it, just what makes you think to do the sustitution